# Python Flask unittest environment variable

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I have an Api in Flask with three config files: **development.cfg**, **production.cfg**, **testing.cfg**

Those files are loaded based on **FLASK_ENV** here:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config.from_pyfile(f"config/{app.config['ENV']}.cfg")

    app.redis = redis.Redis(host=app.config['REDIS_HOST'], port=app.config['REDIS_PORT'])
    app.mongo = MongoClient(host=app.config['MONGO_DB_HOST'], port=int(app.config['MONGO_DB_PORT']))

    init_resources(app)

    return app
```

Now my question is, how do I set the **FLASK_ENV** when executing my tests? I have for instance a test where I need to check a SECRET_KEY which is also environment based, but I'm getting the value from production.

I'm asking myself if I should pass a parameter to `create_app`, something like:

```
def create_app(env):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    environment = app.config['ENV'] if not env else env

    app.config.from_pyfile(f"config/{environment}.cfg")

    app.redis = redis.Redis(host=app.config['REDIS_HOST'], port=app.config['REDIS_PORT'])
    app.mongo = MongoClient(host=app.config['MONGO_DB_HOST'], port=int(app.config['MONGO_DB_PORT']))

    init_resources(app)

    return app
```

Then in my test I would do something like that:

```
class TestLoginMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app(env='testing')
        ....
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: The 2nd pattern looks fine to me, but you can set an env variable in your test with `os.environ['FLASK_ENV'] = 'test'`

Comment: You can set the environment variable is your OS, or set it in Python os.environ. The first solution is likely better. A library like pytest could set it up for you like [here](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/tests/conftest.py).
You may have some problem with some extentions that could be base on this environment variable if you set it directly in your code (I don't know if it could happen, it's just a supposition.)

Comment: thanks. seems like I'm on the right way. setting `os.environ['FLASK_ENV']=testing` works.